# How can I change value from property in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to select property "top" and the value minus (-200px) from inline css.

```
<article class="stack" style="position: absolute; left: 741px; top: 1000px;">
</article>
```

What I want is to count the top: 1000px - 200px

It should decrease the move of the article from 1000px to 800px.

Thanks in advance for any help and sorry if the question is badly asked.

Comment: Why is my question being down-voted?

Comment: Because you don't show any research of your own. SO is not a free code-writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this :

```js
let a = $('article.stack').css('top'); // get the Top value
console.log(a);

$('article.stack').css('top',parseInt(a)-200); //updated the Top value

a = $('article.stack').css('top');
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="stack" style="position: absolute; left: 741px; top: 1000px;">
</article>
```